# XSLT choose which subelement to take

Tags: xslt

I have this MODS

```
<modsCollection>
  <mods ID="master">
    <originInfo>
      <dateOther encoding="8601" type="publication">2016</dateOther>
    </originInfo>
    <originInfo>
      <dateOther encoding="8601" type="onlineFirst">2015</dateOther>
    </originInfo>
    <originInfo>
      <dateOther encoding="8601" type="accepted">2014</dateOther>
    </originInfo>
    <originInfo>
      <dateOther encoding="8601" type="submitted">2013</dateOther>
    </originInfo>
  </mods>
</modsCollection>
```

I need to transform this element  dateOther in to an equivalent dc:date, but I have to take only one dateOther depending on the type attribute (if a publication exists that we take that dateOther, if it doesn't than we take onlineFirst, if it doesn't exist that accepted and so on).

So in the case of the upper MODS we would create

```
<dc:date>2016</dc:date>
```

because a dateOther with attribute type = publication existed, if it didn't we would take the type = onlineFirst, etc.

The order of dateOther appearances can be different and there can be only one, or more of them.

The problem begins with the transformation, I am unable to select all originInfo/dateOther elements so I can compare them by choose

```
<xsl:template match="//mods:mods[@ID = 'master']/mods:originInfo/mods:dateOther">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="...">

      <dc:date>...</dc:date>

    </xsl:when>
    ...
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help to solve this would be helpful.

Comment: Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either an `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:for-each` to sort them into the correct priority, and then pick the first one (NOTE: you haven't told us what namespaces you're using, so I'm not using any namespaces in my example):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="mods[@ID = 'master']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="originInfo/dateOther">
      <xsl:sort select="substring-before(
                            '|publication|onlineFirst|accepted|submitted|', 
                            concat('|', @type, '|')
                        )" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dateOther">
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <date><xsl:value-of select="." /></date>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good attempt, but there is an issue. This will produce wrong result if a value for the "type" attribute can be a substring of another value. Hint: delimiting has to be *on both sides* and on both arguments. Also, it isn't necessary to use `string-length()`

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I was aware of the substring issue but assumed that OP had a discrete number of non-overlapping values. I've fixed that now, and I see now why string-length isn't needed. Thanks for keeping me on my toes.

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as this** -- note you don't need to use the `string-length()` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:dc="my:dc">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vTypes" select="'|publication|onlineFirst|accepted|submitted|'"/>

  <xsl:template match="mods">
    <dc:date>
      <xsl:for-each select="originInfo/dateOther">
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before($vTypes, concat('|', @type, '|'))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="self::node()[$vPos=1]"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </dc:date>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided one, but the elements shuffled so that the result isn't at the top):

```
<modsCollection>
  <mods ID="master">
    <originInfo>
      <dateOther encoding="8601" type="onlineFirst">2015</dateOther>
    </originInfo>
    <originInfo>
      <dateOther encoding="8601" type="accepted">2014</dateOther>
    </originInfo>
    <originInfo>
      <dateOther encoding="8601" type="publication">2016</dateOther>
    </originInfo>
    <originInfo>
      <dateOther encoding="8601" type="submitted">2013</dateOther>
    </originInfo>
  </mods>
</modsCollection>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  <dc:date xmlns:dc="my:dc">2016</dc:date>
```

---

**XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:dc="my:dc">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vTypes" select="'publication','onlineFirst','accepted','submitted'"/>


  <xsl:template match="mods">
    <dc:date>
        <xsl:sequence select=
        "*/*[index-of($vTypes,@type)[1] 
           eq min(current()/*/*/index-of($vTypes,@type)[1])]/text()"/>
    </dc:date>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:

I strongly recommend to try to avoid using XSLT conditional instructions, such as `<xsl:if>`, `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>` ... etc. Using these often leads to convoluted, not easily understandable, spaghetti-like code and is an anti-pattern in both procedural/imperative and declarative/functional programming styles.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to choose from among the different dates, you must do so from the context of their parent. In the given example, it might look something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="mods[@ID = 'master']">
    <!-- other stuff? -->
    <date>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="originInfo/dateOther[@type='publication']">
                <xsl:value-of select="originInfo/dateOther[@type='publication']"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="originInfo/dateOther[@type='onlineFirst']">
                <xsl:value-of select="originInfo/dateOther[@type='onlineFirst']"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="originInfo/dateOther[@type='accepted']">
                <xsl:value-of select="originInfo/dateOther[@type='accepted']"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- and so on -->
        </xsl:choose>
    </date>
    <!-- more stuff? -->
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming XSLT 1.0. There are additional options in XSLT 2.0 - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="mods[@ID = 'master']">
    <!-- other stuff? -->
    <date>
        <xsl:value-of select="(originInfo/dateOther[@type='publication'], originInfo/dateOther[@type='onlineFirst'], originInfo/dateOther[@type='accepted'], originInfo/dateOther[@type='submitted'])[1]"/>
    </date>
    <!-- more stuff? -->
</xsl:template>
```